# Dart is stepping over lines of code, when await is used in async method

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

In my Flutter project I have following code:

```
if(await model.login(loginMailTextController.text, 
   loginPasswordTextController.text)){
   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/main");
}
```

This code calls this function in my model:

```
Future<bool> login(String mail, String password) async {
   _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: mail, password: password);
   return true; //Makes no sense, only for testing
}
```

Which works as expected and the navigator method is called, but if I add the **await** before the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method:

```
Future<bool> login(String mail, String password) async {
   await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
   email: mail, password: password);
   return true; //Debugger won't stop there when a breakpoint is set
}
```

Then the expression in the if statement is false. Also when a breakpoint is set on the marked line, the debugger don't stop. Setting a breakpoint onto the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method works like charme.

Is this a bug or do I make a mistake?

Comment: which `if` statement are you talking about?

Comment: I encountered this as well alas it became better over the months. Adding a `print('foo');` line before the line with `await` often (not always) help to make the debugger behave better.

Comment: @RémiRousselet ´if(await model.login(loginMailTextController.text, 
   loginPasswordTextController.text))´

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Did you reported to dart or flutter team?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Did not work with print, i set it in the login method in the first line, was this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. That's probably the "often (not always)" case :-/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is a big problem, if only the breakpoint don't work it would be not so bad, but this changes the behaviour of my app. Did you reported this bug?

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`. I haven't experienced changing behavior because of that. I never was able to provide a reliable minimal reproduction, this is why I didn't create a bug report.

Comment: "if statement is false" looks like `await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(` throws and the exception is not reported or similar. Try to wrap the code with `try`/`catch`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The last comment was the solution, I just opened it in VS Code and the exception was thrown, only in Android Studio not. Thanks for your help! Write an answer, i will accept and upvote this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181688/discussion-between-niklas-raab-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"if statement is false" looks like `await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(` throws and the exception is not reported or similar.

Try to wrap the code with try/catch